# How to generate a javascript like object in php

Tags: javascript, php, object

I am trying to write empty object in my database: `{}` however, php is always adding quotation marks.

```
$model->maps = json_encode("{}");
```

so my output becomes `"\"{}\""`

And I can't use this either as it will output syntax error `$model->maps = json_encode({});

Also `['' => '']` is saving it as array instead of object. Or using empty array like `= []`, it saves it as `[]`

What is the proper way of handling this case? All I want is empty javascript alike object = `{}`

Comment: Why are you json_encoding it? Don't you want to just save the string `"{}"`?

Comment: Yes but without the quotation marks.

Comment: `"{}"` is already a valid json string, unless you meant to make a json representation of a string. `json_encode` is usually used with an object / array

Comment: My question is: How to generate a javascript like object in php

Comment: `stdClass` is the generic object in php, a little like javascript's Object. So to make a generic object `new stdClass`. Which you can then set properties on and then json_encode it

Comment: You can use `$model->maps = (object) null`

Comment: @AyushMittal it works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://3v4l.org/Vb0Mb

> a string '{}' is already a valid json imo but if you want to use json_encode try the code below.

```
<?php 

// Proper way
$jsonA = json_encode(new stdClass);

// This works but more complex
$jsonB = json_encode((object)array());

echo $jsonA;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $jsonB;
```